# How to use PHP to count the marks of a quiz?

Tags: php, html, function, count

I'm working on a quiz. I want to count the total score obtained by a user after the user has submitted their attempt. How to create a result page that show the marks obtained by the user after they submitted the answer. How do I get the total marks such that each correct answer they get 1/(total number of questions in a quiz)?

This is what I have so far and I can't seem to get it working.

```
<?php
require_once 'getData.php';
require_once 'testing.php';



foreach( $quizHistoryQ as $index => $arr ){
    $answer=$arr['answer'];  


    if (!isset($_POST['submitter'])) {
    } else {
        $num = (int) $_POST['num'];
        $postedanswer = str_replace("_"," ",$_POST['answer']);
        if ($postedanswer == $answers[$num]['0']) {
            $_SESSION['score']++;
            $_SESSION['correct'][] = $postedanswer;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['wrong'][] = $postedanswer;
        }
        if ($num &lt; count($questions)-1) {
            $num++;
        } else {
            $last = true;
            $_SESSION['finished'] = 'yes';
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my question script**

```
<?php

$Titles = array("quizHistoryQ"=>"History Quiz", "quizMathQ" =>" Math Quiz", "quizHTMLq" => "HTML Quiz"); 

$quizHistoryQ = [
    "Q1" => ["questions"=>"ABC?",
        "options" => ["this is option 1",
        "this is option 2",
        "this is option 3"],
        "answer" =>2
    ],
    "Q2" => ["questions"=>"This is the Question String for question 2",
        "options" => ["this is option A",
        "this is option B",
        "this is option C"],
        "answer" =>1
    ],
    "Q3" =>["questions"=>"This is the Question String for question 3",
        "options" => ["this is option X",
        "this is option Y",
        "this is option Z"],
        "answer" =>0
    ]
];

echo 'Title:'. $Titles['quizHistoryQ'];

foreach( $quizHistoryQ as $index => $arr ){
    $question=$arr['questions'];
    $options=$arr['options'];
    $answer=$arr['answer']; 

    echo '<h3>Question: '.$index.': '.$question.'</h3>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($options as $i => $options) {
        echo " <br> <input type='radio' name='{$index}[]' value='{$i}'/>{$options}";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

I'm getting error in these few lines:

[image]

Comment: You should indent the code of your first snippet.

Comment: `if ($num &lt; count($questions)-1)` should be `if ($num < count($questions)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not comparing the answers correctly.

Change this:

```
if ($postedanswer == $answers[$num]['0']) {
```

To this:

```
if ($postedanswer == $answer) {
```

Also, are you call `session_start` anywhere in your code?  It's not clear if you are doing that.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping but I still can't get the code to work. I've posted a snipshot of where the error is that I couldn't figure out what went wrong. Could you kindly help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

First, this is wrong:

```
if ($num &lt; count($questions)-1) {
```

`&lt;` is used in HTML to write the `<` character, but you can't use it in PHP. Change it to this:

```
if ($num < count($questions)-1) {
```

This will take care of the error shown in your editor.

Next:

```
if ($postedanswer == $answers[$num]['0']) {
```

This should be

```
if ($postedanswer == $answer) {
```

since you already assigned the correct answer for the current question here:

```
 $answer=$arr['answer'];
```

Another thing I spotted: You don't really read the value submitted from the form. This line:

```
$postedanswer = str_replace("_"," ",$_POST['answer']);
```

would need a form element with the name `answer`, which you most probably don't have. You didn't post the full form code, so this is guessing, but since you define your radiobuttons with `name='{$index}[]'` it seems a safe guess.

This name is impractical anyway, you end up with arrays containing only one element for each answer since `$index` is the index of the question array, `Q1`, `Q2` etc. You will end up with a `$_POST` array that looks like this:

```
array(3) {
  ["Q1"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["Q2"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(5)
  }
  ["Q3"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

Assuming that only one answer is correct per question you should change the name definition of the radioboxes to this:

```
name='answers[{$index}]'
```

This will result in `$_POST` containing a single array like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["answers"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Q1"]=>
    int(1)
    ["Q2"]=>
    int(5)
    ["Q3"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

This allows you to loop through your questions and easily compare them:

```
foreach( $quizHistoryQ as $index => $arr ){
    $answer = $arr['answer']; 
    $postedanswer = intval( $_POST['answers'][$index] );
    if ( $answer == $postedanswer ) {
        $_SESSION['score']++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping but I'm still getting errors after implementing your suggestion. Maybe I get the wrong order. Is there anyway you could email me the code? Thanks

Comment: I'm not going to write full code for you. If one of these answers solves the main problem from this question, accept the answer. If you get a new problem, ask a new question for it.